# Is there a C++11 or Win32 way to reliably generate and save tracing information?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11, logging, trace

I'm working on a COM component in C++11 (VS2013) which is loaded into another process within a sandbox - though with the ability to write to disk.

I wrote my own tracing function that enters a critical-section/mutex, opens a file for append, writes a timestamp and message, leaves the mutex and returns.

However I'm finding that this tracing function I wrote is a bit flaky: some asserts fail for reasons unknown on different systems - this is a tad ironic considering that tracing functions are used to trace other problems. So I need a reliable tracing system.

Is there any function in the CRT, C++ standard library, or Win32 that provides for a very simple "fire-and-forget" logging function that (generally) won't fail? I've seen `ReportEvent` but I don't think that would work in my case due to the sandbox.

Comment: I'm not aware of any method that does this in C++11 - it's been a while since I used Windows, but I doubt that has it either. It may be good to understand what it is that fails for you, maybe we can solve THAT?

Comment: What about OutputDebugString?

Comment: Or the [event log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385780(v=vs.85).aspx)? Sounds like a bit of an XY problem though.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into Event Tracing for Windows. It pretty much fits your needs: you call EventRegister() at the start of your application, and then call EventWrite() to report an event. You don't need any special system permissions - not even writing to disk. When your program runs normally, it won't generate any output. However, if somebody is listening for the events (with Windows performance recorder, for example), those events will end up in the trace file, which can be viewed with various programs (you can even write a listener yourself, if you prefer that).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx